# Contruct 3d numpy array from array of array of array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

How to efficiently convert

`array([array([array([0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.03333334,...`

to

`array([[[0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.03333334, 0.03333334,...`

Little context of the problem: I have a spark dataframe which a column is an array of array (spark  array type). When I convert it to pandas dataframe, the values become a numpy array of numpy array instead of a numpy 2d array. I could do a `np.stack(df['array of array column'].apply(np.stack).to_numpy())`
but it seems pretty slow with double `np.stack`. I'm seeking for a faster alternative or if there is a way to convert to numpy 2d array directly from the spark dataframe.

Comment: It's the apply that's slow.  Can you tonumpy first, and then iterate the stacks?

Comment: why do you want to transform to pandas?

Comment: @LuizViola I'm using pandas_udf to make tensorflow model prediction

Comment: @hpaulj Do you mean `np.stack([np.stack(x) for x in df['array of array column'].to_numpy()])`? I can give it a try

Comment: `[np.stack(x) for x in df[...].to_numpy()]`.  Get out of pandas as soon as you can.